# EF Code First generates different query locally and in test/prod

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-performance

I have a rather complex Linq-to-SQL query which when run locally or from the AAT environment takes about 2-3 seconds. That's ok-ish. The problem I've got is on the QA and Production servers where the query takes 2-5 minutes(!). When profiling it looks like EF CF generates different SQL in these environments.

We are targeting .net 4.0 using EF 5(4.4)

A quick recap:

- Operation takes 2-3 sec in local/AAT
- Operation takes 2-5 minutes in QA/Prod
- Databases have the same data
- It does not matter which database I connect to or which environment I connect from, the performance issues stay the same.
- Catching the generated SQL and running it through SQL Management studio gives the same execution times.

It seems like the biggest difference in the queries is that one of them uses more outer joins and the other uses more inner joins.

Does anybody have a clue to what's going on?

EDIT: Queries generated [locally](http://pastebin.com/ez6YBr7Y)(22 sec) and on [server](http://pastebin.com/5NAy2Gha)(3min 45sec)

Comment: Post queries here, please.

Comment: Added link to generated queries

Comment: The difference is in some JOINs, which are LEFT OUTER locally and INNER on server. This can happen because of different nullability of fields in DB schemas. Try to compare DB schemas.

Comment: Also, it seems you try to load "everything we need to work". But it is bad idea: you spend memory, MSSQL-optimiser cann't work effectively. Try to decompose this task.

Comment: I don't see how the schemas could differ when I run the same codebase against the same database from different environments. We have decomposing of this task semi-high on our priorities list. But I want to get too the root of this anyways. The difference is huge.

Comment: Stop, stop! You wrote that databaseS has the same data. So I thought, that it's not the same DB, isn't it?

Comment: The performance is still good if we make one of the "high-speed" environments use the slow-speed environment database. So it seems all the difference is which environment the code in run in(which generates the different queries)

Comment: Sorry, cann't help you with EF. You should notice that EF is binary same in both environments.